# Can't load '/usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/DBD/Oracle/Oracle.so' for module DBD::Oracle: libclntsh.so.12.1

Tags: php, linux, perl, centos7, oracle12c

When trying to run a perl script that creates a new oracle database from a PHP web page, an error is raised.

- My PHP page is hosted at linux server (centos7)
- Updated the following environment variables:

  `export ORACLE_HOME=oracle home path
  export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib
  export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH`
- The perl tool is executed from PHP code after clicking on a HTML button:

  `exec("perl scriptName.pl" )`
- The following error is raised:

  > install_driver(Oracle) failed: Can't load '/usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/DBD/Oracle/Oracle.so' for module DBD::Oracle: libclntsh.so.12.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory at /usr/lib64/perl5/DynaLoader.pm line 190.
  >   at (eval 17) line 3.
  >   Compilation failed in require at (eval 17) line 3.
  >   Perhaps a required shared library or dll isn't installed where expected
  >   at (eval 10) line 22698.
- Even though running the perl script alone without calling from web php page by executing: `"perl script.pl"` on the linux server, the code executed and no errors raised.

Comment: Have you checked if the file `/usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/DBD/Oracle/Oracle.so` exists?

Comment: @HåkonHægland yes i did and the file exists.

Comment: Ok, sorry but I am not familiar with running `perl` from a web server so I think I cannot give good advice here. You may try [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=libclntsh.so+cannot+open+shared+object+file&oq=libclntsh.so) or debug DynaLoader.pm. Locate its source file, and go to line 190 and try to understand what is going on..

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the error message contains the important pointer (emphasis mine):

> install_driver(Oracle) failed: Can't load
>   '/usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/DBD/Oracle/Oracle.so' for module
>   DBD::Oracle: **libclntsh.so.12.1: cannot open shared object file: No
>   such file or directory** at /usr/lib64/perl5/DynaLoader.pm line 190. at
>   (eval 17) line 3. Compilation failed in require at (eval 17) line 3.
>   Perhaps a required shared library or dll isn't installed where
>   expected at (eval 10) line 22698.

This problem arises when [Oracle's "instant client"](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/downloads.html) libraries are not available via the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable. This set of libraries contains (among others) `libclntsh.so` (the suffix is version-dependant). Once you have it installed, just make sure the corresponding path is present in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: In almost all cases it's easier to follow the [Instant Client installation instructions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html#ic_x64_inst) recommendation and use `ldconfig` to set the path globally.  Then you never have to worry about setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Comment: Fair enough - `ldconfig` sure is a good way to "make sure the corresponding path is present in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`".